# Issue with Retrofit response in android

Tags: android, json, retrofit, retrofit2

When I add List jsonobject from my ResponseBody pojo class,the textview doesnt display any text as the response is empty. But when I remove the List jsonobject from my pojo , the textview correctly displays the required city and country name.

**API**

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=6324621&APPID=3e29a05ea5759f3ca2ffe14924df07e8

**JSON**

```
{
    "cod": "200",
    "message": 0,
    "cnt": 40,
    "list": [
        {
            "dt": 1574694000,
            "main": {
                "temp": 300.83,
                "temp_min": 300.24,
                "temp_max": 300.83,
                "pressure": 1013,
                "sea_level": 1013,
                "grnd_level": 1009,
                "humidity": 66,
                "temp_kf": 0.59
            },
            "weather": [
                {
                    "id": 800,
                    "main": "Clear",
                    "description": "clear sky",
                    "icon": "01n"
                }
            ],
            "clouds": {
                "all": 0
            },
            "wind": {
                "speed": 1.61,
                "deg": 290
            },
            "sys": {
                "pod": "n"
            },
            "dt_txt": "2019-11-25 15:00:00"
        },
       {},
{},{},
    ],
    "city": {
        "id": 6324621,
        "name": "Powai",
        "coord": {
            "lat": 19.1164,
            "lon": 72.9047
        },
        "country": "IN",
        "timezone": 19800,
        "sunrise": 1574644897,
        "sunset": 1574684949
    }
}
```

**ResponseBody.java:**

```
    import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
    import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

    public class ResponseBody {

        @SerializedName("cod")
        @Expose
        private String cod;
        @SerializedName("message")
        @Expose
        private long message;
        @SerializedName("cnt")
        @Expose
        private long cnt;
        @SerializedName("list")
        @Expose
        private java.util.List<com.example.weatherapp.List> list = null;
        @SerializedName("city")
        @Expose
        private City city;

        public String getCod() {
            return cod;
        }

        public void setCod(String cod) {
            this.cod = cod;
        }

        public long getMessage() {
            return message;
        }

        public void setMessage(long message) {
            this.message = message;
        }

        public long getCnt() {
            return cnt;
        }

        public void setCnt(long cnt) {
            this.cnt = cnt;
        }

        public java.util.List<com.example.weatherapp.List> getList() {
            return list;
        }

        public void setList(java.util.List<com.example.weatherapp.List> list) {
            this.list = list;
        }

        public City getCity() {
            return city;
        }

        public void setCity(City city) {
            this.city = city;
        }

    }
```

**City.java:**

```
    package com.example.weatherapp;


    import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
    import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

    public class City {

        @SerializedName("id")
        @Expose
        private long id;
        @SerializedName("name")
        @Expose
        private String name;

        @SerializedName("country")
        @Expose
        private String country;
        @SerializedName("timezone")
        @Expose
        private long timezone;
        @SerializedName("sunrise")
        @Expose
        private long sunrise;
        @SerializedName("sunset")
        @Expose
        private long sunset;

        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }


        public String getCountry() {
            return country;
        }

        public void setCountry(String country) {
            this.country = country;
        }

        public long getTimezone() {
            return timezone;
        }

        public void setTimezone(long timezone) {
            this.timezone = timezone;
        }

        public long getSunrise() {
            return sunrise;
        }

        public void setSunrise(long sunrise) {
            this.sunrise = sunrise;
        }

        public long getSunset() {
            return sunset;
        }

        public void setSunset(long sunset) {
            this.sunset = sunset;
        }

    }
```

**List.java:**

```
    package com.example.weatherapp;


    import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
    import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

    public class List {

        @SerializedName("dt")
        @Expose
        private long dt;
        @SerializedName("main")
        @Expose
        private Main main;
        @SerializedName("dt_txt")
        @Expose
        private String dtTxt;

        public long getDt() {
            return dt;
        }

        public void setDt(long dt) {
            this.dt = dt;
        }

        public Main getMain() {
            return main;
        }

        public void setMain(Main main) {
            this.main = main;
        }

        public String getDtTxt() {
            return dtTxt;
        }

        public void setDtTxt(String dtTxt) {
            this.dtTxt = dtTxt;
        }

    }
```

**ApiInterface.java:**

```
    package com.example.weatherapp.network;

    import com.example.weatherapp.City;
    import com.example.weatherapp.ResponseBody;

    import retrofit2.Call;
    import retrofit2.http.GET;
    import retrofit2.http.Query;

    public interface ApiInterface {

        @GET("/data/2.5/forecast")
        Call<ResponseBody> RESPONSE_BODY_CALL(@Query("id") long id, @Query("APPID") String api_key);

    }
```

**ApiClient.java:**

```
    package com.example.weatherapp.network;

    import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
    import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor;
    import retrofit2.Retrofit;
    import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

    public class ApiClient {
        static Retrofit retrofit = null;
        static OkHttpClient.Builder okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

        public static Retrofit getRetrofit()
        {
            HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            httpLoggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY); //logs set
            okHttpClient.addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor); // logs added

            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .baseUrl("http://api.openweathermap.org/")
                    .client(okHttpClient.build())
                    .build();

            return retrofit;
        }
    }
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/city"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:background="#bebeee"
            android:text="City, Country"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/humidity"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginVertical="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/city"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            android:background="#ddbdbb"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:text="Humidity"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

I cant figure out the reason by the textview is showing empty when I do not remove the List pojo object from ResponseBody.class

Comment: add all json list fields to pojo class of list and try again

Comment: Did that earlier too but no result. same issue

Comment: what error u are getting when invoking api with response body containing list?

Comment: no error @darwin . Only i get a empty response

Comment: I think the issue may be parsing response

Comment: which callback function does the api call hits? onResponse() or onFailure() ?

Comment: onFailure() @darwin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203172/discussion-between-darwin-and-prajwal-w).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comments its clear that the issue is with the ResponseBody class.

Change the data type of variable temp_kf from the class Main.Java to double.

The current data type for the variable temp_kf is long, so when Gson tries to convert the value containing fractional parts it throws exception.

Comment: Great @darwin This solved my issue. I kind of generated by pojo classes from jsonschema2pojo.com site. Seems to be having a bug in the site. Thanks bud!

Comment: The jsonschema2pojo.org has an option to treat numbers as double instead of long. You can enable that check box option to generate all variables having number value as double data type.

Comment: but wont tat affect the variables they hv long datatype then?

Comment: I am not sure about that, I have seen an option in the settings

Answer (score 0):

Please use `ArrayList` in place of `java.util.List`

```
 @SerializedName("list")
 @Expose
 private ArrayList<CityList> list = null;
```

or change `com.example.weatherapp.List` name such as `CityList`

Comment: I changed to ArrayList but still no change @Divyanshu

Answer (score 0):

1.On you **ApiInterface** Remove extra "/" from @GET query

Make it       "data/2.5/forecast" as a "/" already added to your base url

```
@GET("data/2.5/forecast")
Call<ResponseBody> RESPONSE_BODY_CALL(@Query("id") long id, @Query("APPID") String api_key);
```

2.Remove null asignment from list.

Example : You initialized list as null

```
@SerializedName("list")
private List<ListItem> list;
```

ListItem :

```
public class ListItem{

    @SerializedName("dt")
    private int dt;

    @SerializedName("dt_txt")
    private String dtTxt;

    @SerializedName("weather")
    private List<WeatherItem> weather;

    @SerializedName("main")
    private Main main;

    @SerializedName("clouds")
    private Clouds clouds;

    @SerializedName("sys")
    private Sys sys;

    @SerializedName("wind")
    private Wind wind;

    public void setDt(int dt){
        this.dt = dt;
    }

    public int getDt(){
        return dt;
    }

    public void setDtTxt(String dtTxt){
        this.dtTxt = dtTxt;
    }

    public String getDtTxt(){
        return dtTxt;
    }

    public void setWeather(List<WeatherItem> weather){
        this.weather = weather;
    }

    public List<WeatherItem> getWeather(){
        return weather;
    }

    public void setMain(Main main){
        this.main = main;
    }

    public Main getMain(){
        return main;
    }

    public void setClouds(Clouds clouds){
        this.clouds = clouds;
    }

    public Clouds getClouds(){
        return clouds;
    }

    public void setSys(Sys sys){
        this.sys = sys;
    }

    public Sys getSys(){
        return sys;
    }

    public void setWind(Wind wind){
        this.wind = wind;
    }

    public Wind getWind(){
        return wind;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return 
            "ListItem{" + 
            "dt = '" + dt + '\'' + 
            ",dt_txt = '" + dtTxt + '\'' + 
            ",weather = '" + weather + '\'' + 
            ",main = '" + main + '\'' + 
            ",clouds = '" + clouds + '\'' + 
            ",sys = '" + sys + '\'' + 
            ",wind = '" + wind + '\'' + 
            "}";
        }
}
```

Comment: I removed  @Expose and renamed name of list class to listitem. You can try

Comment: I have updated my answer please try it and accept my answer if it work